# Try to svn checkout, but get: svn: '.' is already a working copy for a different URL

Tags: svn, svn-checkout, working-copy

I'm trying to svn checkout into my public_html folder, but I get this error:
svn: '.' is already a working copy for a different URL

My brother already set up a boiler plate site for me, but I've changed it and put those changes into a repo of my own. How do I make this folder not be a working copy of the repo he set up originally?

Can I delete the public_html folder and make a new one? I'm fine with starting from scratch, as I'm going to just checkout an already installed drupal site onto this site.

I saw in another question that a solution may be to simply delete the .svn directory. I tried this, but it said permission denied for several subdirectories in .svn.

Thanks in advance for ANY help, hope this question isn't too dumb...

Comment: If you don't have permission to delete public_html/.svn, then you won't be able to delete public_html either.

Comment: SVN from cmd line! you should totally use tortoise svn http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sequence of commands should do it if you're in a hurry.

There's gotta be a way to update the working copy's reference url, but I don't know it off-hand.

```
$ svn diff > ../changes.patch
$ rm -rf * ..?*
$ svn checkout url
$ patch -p < ../changes.patch
```

Comment: This is (approximately) `svn switch`. Whoever ends up here from Google may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/933468/2279059

Answer (score 10):

You could try "svn switch".  In the example at http:// svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s05.html, it's as easy as:

```
 $ svn switch http:// svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch
```

But since you have subdirectory permissions issues, your plan to re-create public_html sounds like the best solution; just beware of typos with 'rm'.  Try 'mv' to just move the old directory out of the way, which doesn't depend on subdirectory permissions.

You can use:

```
 $ mv public_html old_public_html
 $ mkdir public_html
 $ chmod 755 public_html
 $ cd public_html
 $ svn checkout url
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a connection with your brother's repo, then just remove all his `.svn` dirs.

The permission issue is not related to SVN, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best option in your case is to delete the folder and create it again doing the checkout from SVN

Answer (score 0):

> I saw in another question that a
>   solution may be to simply delete the
>   .svn directory. I tried this, but it
>   said permission denied for several
>   subdirectories in .svn.

Even when you can not delete directories you may move them away:

```
$ mv .svn /tmp/dustbin
```

edit:

You should have write access at least to your home directory:

```
$ mv ~/public_html /tmp/dustbin
$ mkdir ~/public_html
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error ("... is already a working copy for a different URL") just now in Eclipse 3.5.  I was trying to check out a particular branch of a project from the Eclipse "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective (the Subclipse subversion client adapter from tigris.org).  I had drilled into `[project] | branches | [branch]` that I was interested in, then did right-click on the branch that I was interested in and selected `Checkout`; this led to the error.

For me, the fix was to instead go to the "Java EE" perspective, right-click on my project, and select `Replace With | Branch/Tag...` from the context menu.  Doing this, I was successfully able download the branch I was interested in.

Comment: That "Replace With | Branch/Tag..." is probably Eclipses name for SVN SWITCH (see below). If any Eclipse/SVN guru could confirm this, it would make this thread clearer. (In my opinion the "switch" is exactly what is needed here, and it was designed for exactly this situation.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I simply go to the J2EE perspective, right click on the project, and select Delete before I attempt to checkout a new branch, it solves this problem.