# How do I fix the SVN error: "is already a working copy for a different URL"?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In attempting to figure out why we are getting this error I looked [at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933390/try-to-svn-checkout-but-get-svn-is-already-a-working-copy-for-a-different)

Unfortunately it is not the same issue and the answers were unhelpful.

Our repository has an external property - and it was this directory that was showing the error when doing a "fresh" checkout.

The issue we discovered is:

1. The project has an external property on a folder
2. We someone then added a folder in the same place with the name of the subfolder in that property

\trunk\project
\trunk\project\foo has an external with property of: bar pointing to some url

someone then committed a folder called bar under foo

This screws up everything.  (there are now two copies of the folder with conflicting information about the svn url)

Comment: So... this is both a question and its answer? You should rephrase the question as a question, and then post the answer as an answer.

Comment: Your self-answered question seems somewhat helpful, but would be much more so if you split up question/problem statement and solution.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me - I had checked out `ACMECorp` and not `ACMECorp\trunk`. When I tried to delete the local ACMECorp directory and check out the folder one level down I got this error.

Undo the local delete, right click and select **Switch...**. Select the actual path you want to check out (in my case 'ACMECorp\trunk' and tick the 'ignore ancestry' option.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this we did the following:

From the repo browser we deleted the non-external folder (then branched the external reference.  This second step might not be necessary but was for us since we were branching the main project.)

Not sure if anyone will benefit from this but it caused us to scratch our heads.

It is almost a bug in svn to allow that...

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I delected my local WD and tried to checkout again. Be sure to give the exact path of the SVN directory as there will be other directories with .svn files so it will have a conflict.