# Eclipse: sharing project failed. already a working copy for a different URL

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using eclipse luno (4.4) in the linux environment.
When I sharing project with svn repository in eclipse, it gives this error.

**"Sharing failed. ... is already a working copy for a different URL; perform update to complete it"**

I added normal java project to that svn repository successfully. But when I add another project (a java web project) it gives this error.

May be this is because I have tried to add this project so many times. But I deleted those directories with "svn delete [URL]" command and they were successfully deleted.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?
The error occur at the last step in eclipse sharing project dialog.

how can I update it? svn update is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try to svn checkout, but get: svn: '.' is already a working copy for a different URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933390/try-to-svn-checkout-but-get-svn-is-already-a-working-copy-for-a-different)

Answer (score 0):

**Following steps will help you**

1. -Remove .svn directory from your project
2. -refresh your project on eclipse
3. -share project to svn